# Good graph plotting app

Tags: windows, charts

Does anyone know of a free graph plotting app for Windows (or an online tool) that can plot something like this?

> X<sub>n+1</sub>= r sin (π * X<sub>n</sub>)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to suggest WolframAlpha, but it has trouble with the "r*". The best I could do is [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=g[n%2B1]%3D%3Dsin(g[n]*Pi)).

[image]

Comment: Definitely helps. I just tried this g[n+1]==(4*(sin(g[n]*Pi))) (wish I could get the graph could be a bit bigger though).

Comment: Click the Download as PDF at lover right, the graph there is LITTLE bit bigger

Comment: And - I forgot - you can install Mathematica Player, click the Live Mathematica in lover left corner and resize the graph however you want. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd try [Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) or [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/)/[Matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/). If you had an Apple, the built-in [Grapher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapher) would do the job.

Comment: wow, spacetime is awesome

Answer (score 1):

See [Science: Math: Software: Graphing](http://www.dmoz.org/Science/Math/Software/Graphing/) for a few dozens of plotting applications.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend **[matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/)** (requires some basic Python knowledge).

> matplotlib is a python 2D plotting library which produces publication
>   quality figures in a variety of hardcopy formats and interactive
>   environments across platforms. matplotlib can be used in python
>   scripts, the python and ipython shell (ala MATLAB® or Mathematica®),
>   web application servers, and six graphical user interface toolkits.

The documentation is still under development, so mastering MPL can take some time, but it's obviously worth it in the end if you take a look at the examples [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/gallery.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try **[Graph](http://www.padowan.dk/)** by Ivan Johansen.

> Graph is an open source application used to draw mathematical graphs
>   in a coordinate system. Anyone who wants to draw graphs of functions
>   will find this program useful. The program makes it very easy to
>   visualize a function and paste it into another program. It is also
>   possible to do some mathematical calculations on the functions.

[image]