# Grapher - For windows

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anyone know of a good graph plotting app](https://superuser.com/questions/55425/anyone-know-of-a-good-graph-plotting-app)

We've got Grapher which is only for mac.
Do we have something similar for Windows?

Comment: This could be regarded as a duplicate to a lot of questions which are found when "plotting functions" is searched. Like http://superuser.com/questions/55425/anyone-know-of-a-good-graph-plotting-app and http://superuser.com/questions/103582/how-to-easily-plot-graph-using-preferably-free-software

Answer (score 1):

[Seems like](http://lifehacker.com/309828/power-up-windows-calculator-with-power-calculator) [Windows Power Toys for XP](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx) include a graphing calculator.